# How do I multiply a matrix with a vector in gonum?

Tags: go, math, matrix, blas, gonum

I want to multiply a `mat.Dense` Matrix with a `mat.VecDense` Vector, but obviously `mat.Dense`  nor `mat.VecDens` do not implement the Matrix interface or define a method to multiply a matrix with a vector. How would I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved it.

`mat.NewVecDense(...)` returns a `*mat.VecDense`, that implements a method `func MulVec(a mat.Matrix, b mat.Vector)`

Here is a test to validate the functionality

```
func TestMatrixVectorMul(t *testing.T) {
    a := mat.NewDense(3, 3, []float64{
        1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,
    })
    b := mat.NewVecDense(3, []float64{
        1, 2, 3,
    })
    actual := make([]float64, 3)
    c := mat.NewVecDense(3, actual)

    // this was the method, I was looking for. 
    c.MulVec(a, b)
    expected := []float64{14, 32, 50}
    assert.Equal(t, expected, actual)
}
```